# Trouble Writing to Serial Port with Java RXTX Library

Tags: java, bluetooth, arduino, serial-port, rxtx

I'm trying to send some bytes from java code to a bluetooth module that is connected to an Arduino. Here is my code.

```
import gnu.io.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class ArduinoSerialWriter {
    private static OutputStream arduinoOutputStream;

    public static void init() throws NoSuchPortException, PortInUseException,
        UnsupportedCommOperationException, IOException {
        SerialPort arduino = (SerialPort) CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("COM6")
            .open(ArduinoSerialWriter.class.getName(), 2000);
        arduino.setSerialPortParams(9600,
            SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
        arduinoOutputStream = arduino.getOutputStream();
    }

    public static void writeToArduino(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
        arduinoOutputStream.write(bytes);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ArduinoSerialWriter.init();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            arduinoOutputStream.write(new byte[]{(byte) -1, (byte) 90, (byte) 40});
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The `init()` seems to be working properly and connecting to the bluetooth module. The problem is that the call to `arduinoOutputStream.write()` is blocking indefinitely. I can also tell that the bytes have not been sent because the Arduino is not doing anything. However, no exceptions were thrown.

I read somewhere that it might be because the Arduino is resetting and needs time before it is ready to receive data, so I tried adding `Thread.sleep(10000);` before writing to the port, but that didn't change anything.

I also used a debugger to figure out where exactly the code was blocking and I traced it to these lines from the write(byte[]) method from RXTXPort.class in the RXTX library:

```
RXTXPort.this.waitForTheNativeCodeSilly();
RXTXPort.this.writeArray(var1, 0, var1.length, RXTXPort.this.monThreadisInterrupted);
```

From what I can gather, `waitForTheNativeCodeSilly();` is called right before the bytes are actually sent in the next line, and this is where the code freezes.

I also tried adding `arduinoOutputStream.flush();` after the call to the write method, but that didn't help either because the code froze before that line was even reached.

Any help would be appreciated.

Update:

I tried using removing the bluetooth module and using the USB cable for the Arduino instead and it worked perfectly. I think there might be something I need to setup with the bluetooth module.

It is an HC-06 bluetooth module. Here's where I got it from:
https://www.amazon.ca/JMT-Wireless-Bluetooth-Serial-Arduino/dp/B00HXAE0PQ/

The only thing I'm doing to set it up is going to manage bluetooth devices on my windows 10 pc and clicking pair. It says paired underneath it, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Update Again:

I tried sending data to the bluetooth module using the serial monitor in the Arduino IDE, and the entire IDE completely froze. The only way I could shut it down was by killing the process in task manager. I'm fairly certain the Arduino IDE is having the same problem that I am, so its definitely something to do with the bluetooth chip and not my code itself.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had the completely wrong idea. I was much better off using bluetooth connection as opposed to trying to treat the bluetooth chip as a COM port. I guess I was just fixated on that because I was used to it from Arduino.

I used the bluecove library for java and its working great now!